# How to convert HTML to Docx using .net core, c# for free

Tags: c#, html, pdf, .net-core, docx

I need to convert HTML to DOCX or PDF to DOCX for free, but i can not to find any fresh answers.
I tried this code:

```
 public static byte[] HtmlToWord(String html)
    {
        const string filename = "test.docx";
        if (File.Exists(filename)) File.Delete(filename);

        using (MemoryStream generatedDocument = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (WordprocessingDocument package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(
                   generatedDocument, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
            {
                MainDocumentPart mainPart = package.MainDocumentPart;
                if (mainPart == null)
                {
                    mainPart = package.AddMainDocumentPart();
                    new Document(new Body()).Save(mainPart);
                }

                HtmlConverter converter = new HtmlConverter(mainPart);
                Body body = mainPart.Document.Body;

                var paragraphs = converter.Parse(html);
                for (int i = 0; i < paragraphs.Count; i++)
                {
                    body.Append(paragraphs[i]);
                }

                mainPart.Document.Save();
            }

            return generatedDocument.ToArray();
        }
```

But in this code I am getting the null reference exception
`var paragraphs = converter.Parse (html);`
can someone help solve the current error or advise other ways to convert

```
Update 1
```

This html throw null reference exception. I generate it of razor view.

Code to generate html of razor view

```
 private readonly IRazorViewEngine _razorViewEngine;
        private readonly ITempDataProvider _tempDataProvider;
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        public ViewRenderService(IRazorViewEngine razorViewEngine,
            ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider,
            IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _razorViewEngine = razorViewEngine;
            _tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        public async Task<string> RenderToStringAsync(string viewName, object model)
        {
            var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext { RequestServices = _serviceProvider };
            var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());

            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                var viewResult = _razorViewEngine.FindView(actionContext, viewName, false);

                if (viewResult.View == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException($"{viewName} does not match any available view");
                }

                var viewDictionary = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary())
                {
                    Model = model
                };

                var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                    actionContext,
                    viewResult.View,
                    viewDictionary,
                    new TempDataDictionary(actionContext.HttpContext, _tempDataProvider),
                    sw,
                    new HtmlHelperOptions()
                );

                await viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);
                return sw.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: null reference means an object is null... Since the "converter" is istantiate two lines before (converter = new HtmlConverter) it cannot be null. The only variable that can be null is the "html" that is passed as argument of the funcion. Are you sure you're passing something valid inside it?

Comment: Yes, I am sure, I generated html before in code and I checked it in debug mode

Comment: now I tested it with another html code, it's simpler and it worked now, although the previous html was also valid